# Assign an specific user to many projects with Azure DEVOPS CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface, devops

I'm newbbie on Azure DEVOPS CLI, and I need  assign an specific user to all projects in my organization using AZURE DEVOPS CLI. The total of projects of the organization it´s about 25 projects.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a user to all projects in your organization using Azure DevOps CLI, you can refer to the followings.

**Prerequisites**

- Ensure the user has been added into your organization. If not, you can add the user from UI or using DevOps CLI [az devops user add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-user-add).
- You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group.

**Steps**

1. Run [az devops project list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/project?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-project-list) to get all the project id.
2. Run [az devops security group list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-list) to get the descriptor of the target group to which you want to add the user.
3. Run [az devops security group membership add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group/membership?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-membership-add) to add the user to the target group.

**Sample**

The following PowerShell scripts add the user to the Readers group of all projects. Replace the value of `userEmail`, `organization`, `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` and `displayName` based on your requirement.

```
# Define user and organization details
$userEmail = "{The user email}"
$organization = "{Org name}"

# Define Personal Access Token (PAT) as environment variable for authentication
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '{PAT}'

# Get list of all projects in the organization
$projects = az devops project list --organization https://dev.azure.com/$organization | ConvertFrom-Json

# Loop through each project
foreach ($project in $projects.value) {
    $projectId = $project.id

    # Get the Readers group descriptor for the project
    $groupid = az devops security group list --organization https://dev.azure.com/$organization --project $projectId --query "graphGroups[?displayName=='Readers'].descriptor| [0]"

    # Add the user to the Readers group
    az devops security group membership add --group-id $groupid --member-id $userEmail --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to assign user to entire organization, Once the user is assigned at the organization level, The user has access to all the Projects inside it. Reference [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users.md).

**Command:-**

```bash
az login
az devops user add --email-id ankitxxxx@gmail.com --license-type stakeholder --output table --send-email-invite true --org https://dev.azure.com/org-name/
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]